# Using WEKA in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, weka, naivebayes

I am loading a model which I have saved from the WEKA Explorer to my Java code as seen below. I am now trying to give it an instance in the form of a .arff file so that I can get a prediction however it is giving an output of **NaN 0.0** every time.

The prediction should be in the form of Levels (eg. Level 1).
The Screen Shot attached is the output I get.
I also attached another screenshot of a dummy .arff file I am giving the model.

```
try {
            NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
            nb = (NaiveBayes) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("Models/NaiveBayesModel.model");

            DataSource source1 = new DataSource(final_filePath);
            Instances testDataSet = source1.getDataSet();
            testDataSet.setClassIndex(testDataSet.numAttributes() - 1);

            double actualValue = testDataSet.instance(0).classValue();
            Instance newInst = testDataSet.instance(0);
            double NaiveBayes = nb.classifyInstance(newInst);
            System.out.println(actualValue + " " + NaiveBayes);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeQht.png)
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE8LM.png)

How can I fix this, please?

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: What line actually throws the error?

Comment: In order to test this, the model file and testing data set may be necessary (or at the very least, a description of the structure of the data - are you sure the instances match the model that you created?)

Comment: @markspace There is no actual line of error. The output given is simply NaN 0.0 which is not what I want. I need the prediction in the form of "Level 3" for example

Comment: @Marco13 I can make the entire codebase available for you if you need as well as a dummy dataset sample.

Comment: A [MCVE] is the preferred way. Otherwise, the question will hardly be useful for future readers.

Comment: @Marco13 I understand however I am unable to share the data as it is sensitive and the file itself is too large. I can, however, give you the code via google drive with the model if you are interested in helping me out.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue with a reduced/anonymized data set? You see, one could now create a "dummy test" for the bayes classifier (maybe using the Iris dataset...), and it would *likely* work. (If it didn't work, it would rather be a an issue that should be reported (as a bug) to the Weka folks). The point here is fleshing out what the *reason* for the observed behavior it (even though this means that you might have to invest some time on your own (and even though you would then likely be able to resolve it yourself))

Comment: @Marco13 yes, it is, the dummy data still be the same structure, however, names will be fictitious rather than the actual sensitive data. Can you please get in touch with me via email?

Comment: You could contact me, but this would not be beneficial for others (and I'd hesitate (and could not promise) to invest time here just to fix your, individual, specific problem. I mean, you could hire me as a consultant, but that wouldn't be worth it either...). You're printing the classifier to the console. It should print some information about the internal structure of the model. Can you add the output of this?

Comment: @Marco13 The output is attached above.

Comment: That's not what I meant (or at least, expected). When you do `System.out.println(NaiveBayes)`, then it should print something like `Naive Bayes Classifier ... Class ... Attribute`, in a tabular form. If it does not do so, maybe the model was not written out properly? It's really hard to give helpful hints here...

Comment: @Marco13 I am not getting that output hence why I am seeking help. The model was saved after it was trained on the Weka Explorer using the normal options. When it is loaded back on the Weka Explorer it predicts just fine hence why I do not think the model was written out properly.